# How to get decreasing sequential list from number in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a number in python

n = 4

what I want is a countdown list like this:

[4,3,2,1]

Do I need to build a custom function or is there some one line magic that can take any number and create a list.

Comment: ```list(range(n,0,-1))```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range()` functions's `step` parameter

```
>>> n=4
>>> list(range(n,0,-1))
[4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `range()` function. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

`range(start, end, step)`

- start - Number where you want to start from
- end - Number where you want to end (not incuding end)
- step - How much should the numbers be incremented at each step.

So in your case it should be

> `range(4,0,-1)`

If you want a `list` - Then  `list(range(4,0,-1))` will give you `[4,3,2,1]`.

Comment: ```list(range(4,0,-1))```. ```range``` is a generator

Comment: A `range` object isn't actually a generator, it's a sequence. In many situations it may be just as good to as a list (though sometimes you *do* need a real list, like if you need to mutate it later).

Answer (score 0):

Well I world suggest you to use numpy as it is easier to use but if you want to use a function, you can use it too.

Well if you use numpy then you have to `np.arange()`. You can use it just by passing one parameter but at that point, the array will start from 0 to the number one less from that is passed. But so f you want to make a function then a for loop will be used in it.

I have added the code for both suggestions down bellow. Both of them give the same result `[4,3,2,1]`. The `[::-1]` is to revert the list i.e. from `[0,1,2]` to `[2,1,0]`.

```
import numpy as np

print(list(np.arange(1,5))[::-1])

def n (a):
    l = []
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        l.append(i)
    return l[::-1]

print(n(4))
```